# apollo-client integrate with aws lambda

Tags: lambda, apollo-client

I'm using apollo-client on the front end to send graphql requests to my aws lambda app.  I looked at using apollo on the lambda as well, but this seems to complicated, instead I just want to use plain graphqljs, how do I go about this?  All the examples I looked seem to itnegrate with apollo on the lambda end.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't pure Lambda as the public endpoint, but if you want to use AWS AppSync (https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/) you can have that as your GraphQL layer and then use an AWS Lambda resolver to execute your business logic. Here is information on using Lambda resolvers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-lambda-resolvers.html

At that point you can use the Apollo client with AppSync and choose your authorization method. Using React as an example, it looks like this:

```
import AWSAppSyncClient from 'aws-appsync'
import AppSyncConfig from './aws-exports'
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo'
import { Rehydrated } from 'aws-appsync-react' // this is included with aws-appsync

import App from './App'

const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
  url: AppSyncConfig.graphqlEndpoint,
  region: AppSyncConfig.region,
  auth: {
    type: AppSyncConfig.authType,
    apiKey: AppSyncConfig.apiKey,
  }
})

const WithProvider = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Rehydrated>
      <App />
    </Rehydrated>
  </ApolloProvider>
)

export default WithProvider
```